# bing search api php filter

Tags: php, api, filter, bing

i'm using the following php to connect to bing api:
how can i add filter (Size:Small)?
the code is from bing documentation and it works fine.
i'm using this code to connect to bing and redirect the response to an iOS app.
please help...

```
 <?php
{

$accountKey = ‘XXXXXXXXX’;
$auth = base64_encode("$accountKey:$accountKey");
$data = array(
  'http'            => array(
  'request_fulluri' => true,
  'ignore_errors'   => true,
  'header'          => "Authorization: Basic " . $auth));
$context   = stream_context_create($data);
$query     = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : htmlspecialchars($_GET["searchtext"]);
$serviceOp = isset($_GET['sop']) ? $_GET['sop'] : 'Web';
$market    = isset($_GET['market']) ? $_GET['market'] : 'en-us';
$ServiceRootURL = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/';  
$WebSearchURL   = $ServiceRootURL . 'Image?$format=json&Image.Filters=+filterui:imagesize-large+filterui:photo-photo+filterui:face-face&Query=';
$request = $WebSearchURL . urlencode( '\'' . $query. '\'') ;
// Get the response from Bing.
$response = file_get_contents($request, 0, $context);                    
                    $jsonobj = json_decode($response);

                   // echo('<ul ID="resultList">');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

            echo($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove all image filters from $WebSearchURL variable,
and then add your image filters with this way:

```
$request = $WebSearchURL . urlencode( '\'' . $query. '\'').'&ImageFilters=';
$request = $request . urlencode( '\'' .'Size:Large+Face:Face'. '\'');
```

Hope it works with you :)